# Autosys box runs ahead of its start time

Tags: autosys

Autosys boxes are configured with conditions as below:

```
Box1 - Start_time : 7:00 AM ,some conditions..
Box2 - Start_time : 10:00 Am  ,condition : f(box1)
Box3 - Start_time : 1:00 pm  ,condition : f(box3)
```

But all the 3 boxes start at  7:00 am , box2 & box3 at 10:00 am & 1:00 pm.
Am I missing something here ? Why are box2 & box3 runד at 10:00 & 1:00pm though the start_time is not met?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a condition is met, all conditions get re-checked. I would suggest adding lookback to your condition.

```
Box1 - Start_time : 7:00 AM ,some conditions..
Box2 - Start_time : 10:00 Am  ,condition : f(box1,04.00)
Box3 - Start_time : 1:00 pm  ,condition : f(box3)
```

Not sure about box3 being dependent on each other.
Hope this helps.
Dave